# QMessageBox is not displaying whole title

Tags: c++, qt, resize, qmessagebox

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // first
    QMessageBox box(0);
    box.setText("short text");
    box.setWindowTitle("looooooooooooooooong text");
    box.setMinimumSize(800, 0);

    box.exec();


    // second
    //QMessageBox::warning(0, "looooooooooooooooong text", "short text");

    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

Both approaches produce this messagebox, where title is not displayed properly. I have tried to resize dialog widget by it doesn't help. How can I force QMessageBox to display whole title?

As a workaround I can add trailing spaces to title text but I think there should be better solution.

```
aminasya@aminasya-desktop:~/qt$ qmake --version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: How have you tried to resize the dialog widget?

Comment: By calling `QWidget::resize()`

Comment: Try [setMinimumSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight it doesn't help too. I updated question.

Comment: The QMessageBox width is based on the text of the message box. Either you can add some spaces in to the text until your title is visible or go with the answer below!!

Comment: What's the Qt version and platform you're running it on?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create `QMessageBox` with constructor which qt help mentioned in `qmessagebox.cpp` but it didnt worked for me too. 
For some reason `QMessageBox` adjust size to fit the window title doesn't work. However you can adjust `MessageBox` size by creating your own sublclass of `QMessageBox`.

Please see example below;

```
class MyMessageBox : public QMessageBox
    {
    public:
        explicit MyMessageBox(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMessageBox(parent) { }
        MyMessageBox(const QString &title, const QString &text, Icon icon,
                     int button0, int button1, int button2,
                     QWidget *parent = 0,
                     Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::Dialog | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint) :
            QMessageBox(title, text, icon, button0, button1, button2, parent, f) { }


        static void about(QString title, QString text)
        {
            MyMessageBox aboutBox(title, text, QMessageBox::Information, 0, 0, 0, NULL);

            aboutBox.setText(title);
            aboutBox.setText(text);
            QIcon icon = aboutBox.windowIcon();
            QSize size = icon.actualSize(QSize(64, 64));
            aboutBox.setIconPixmap(icon.pixmap(size));

            aboutBox.exec();
        }

        void showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
        {
            QMessageBox::showEvent(event);
            QWidget *textField = findChild<QWidget *>("qt_msgbox_label");
            if (textField != NULL)
            {
                // getting what ever my system has set for the window title font
                QFont font = QFont("Ubuntu Bold", 11);
                // you might want to make it more generic by detecting the actuall font
                // or using smth like this:
                //QFont font = QApplication::font("QWorkspaceTitleBar");

                QFontMetrics fm(font);
                int width = qMax(fm.width(windowTitle()) + 50, textField->minimumWidth());
                textField->setMinimumWidth(width);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I got the idea, but can't understand why are you explicitly setting text, title and icon in about method. Arn't they already set in constructor?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that QMessageBox, when launched with exec() checks the length of the body text and automatically adjusts the size, ignoring the fact that the title text may be longer. Though not ideal, you can change it just afterwards with a QTimer, as demonstrated here:

```
QMessageBox* box = new QMessageBox;
box->setText("short text");
box->setWindowTitle("looooooooooooooooong text");

QTimer* pTimer = new QTimer;
pTimer->setSingleShot(true);
QObject::connect(pTimer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){
   box->setMinimumWidth(400);
   pTimer->deleteLater();
});
pTimer->start(0);
box->exec();
```

Since this occurs after the message box is launched, the change in size is visible.

The better solution would simply be to create your own MessageBox, derived from QDialog. After all, the QMessageBox class is just a convenience widget.

Comment: I tried this solution. It worked if I change pTimer->start(30) instead of pTimer->start(0). But it also prints this message `QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
` I have modified this code. I have made callback function a member slot function of empty class.

Comment: I've just checked and I don't the the warning that you mention, so either it's specific to Linux, or something else is causing it. I suspect the timer being 0 or 30 is a timing issue. Using '0' means that the event is posted as soon as the event queue is processed. If it occurs before the MessageBox is launched, then you wouldn't see any difference. Either way, it sounds like it's working for you ;O)

Answer (score 1):

Since `exec()` and `show()` both override your minimum size based on the contents of the box's text, the simple solution is not to use `exec()` *and* to set the minimum size after the box has been shown. In any case, you should never use `exec()` in dialogs anyway.

Note: Window titles are non-portable. Your UI must still make sense without a window title. For example, on OS X the message box window titles are invisible.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QMessageBox box;
  box.setText("short text");
  box.setWindowTitle("looooooooooooooooong text");
  box.show();
  box.setMinimumSize(qMax(box.minimumWidth(), 800), box.minimumHeight());

  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: This code is not working for me. It displays old messagebox.

Comment: @Ashot What do you mean by the "old" messagebox?

Comment: I mean It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Probably something else needs to be done on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since the message box width is adjusted to the width of the text, a simple answer seems to be to pad the text string with spaces:

```
QString title = "This is a looooooooooooooooooooooooong title";
QString txt   = "Short Text";
QMessageBox box;
box.setWindowTitle(title);
int titleLen = title.length();
int txtLen   = txt.length();
if (txtLen < titleLen)
{
    int diff = titleLen - txtLen;
    txt.resize(titleLen + (diff * 2),' '); // diff * 2 is extra padding;
}
box.setText(txt);
box.exec();
```

You can see I kludged the padding length because of variable width fonts.  But hey, the kludge works for me.